# Fastest way to write a list of integers to file

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have a list of integers that I need to write to a file.

I wonder if there is any faster way to write those integers to the file than this approach which takes 1.77 seconds?

*(The list do have integers from the beginning because they are processed as integers in other functions that needs integers for fast calculations)*

```
void writeToFile()
{
    List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
    {
        list1.Add(123);
    }

    //Approach takes: 1.77 seconds
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    StreamWriter writer = null; FileStream fs = null;
    fs = new FileStream("C:/test.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite); 
    writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(list1[i]);
    }
    writer.Close(); fs.Close();

    DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan span = end - start;
    MessageBox.Show(span.TotalSeconds.ToString());
}
```

Comment: It is `@"C:\test.txt"`, not `"C:/test.txt"`.

Comment: Using the [Dispose pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispose_pattern#Language_constructs) would make your code look cleaner.

Comment: "if there is any faster way".... buy i quicker hard disk... (0,405 seconds)

Comment: Your sample takes 646 milliseconds on my machine. This one takes 595 milliseconds (if worth it):
 File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\test.txt", list1.Select(l => l.ToString()));
BTW you are not writing integers but strings to a file. If you write that as integers (binary) it should be faster.

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you need it to be faster? 1.77 seconds is not exactly a ton of time, it could be if you need to write thounsands of files, but at that point you should really consider why you are writing that many files and if there is a better way. To speed up disk access, as mentioned by others, you need 1) reduce concurrent write requests. 2) buy a faster drive. These micro optimization things puzzle my mind, I coulnd't care less for those 1.77 seconds, unless there is some other problem arrising from that.

Comment: I do have a descent SSD drive though. I will actually write many thousands of those files. Perheps 30 thousands of files. This is why I am checking if there could be a much better/faster way to write the file. As you say I wonder about those concurrent `writeline` requests if they takes up alot of time.

Comment: @Andreas **1.** Is your `list1` sorted? **2.** How many elements does it mostly include? Does it always contain 5_000_000 elements? If it is sorted, always contain 5_000_000 elements, and this elements are always between 0-9_999_999 than this values can be stored in the file in a special format. For example, if `list1` includes a continuous sequence of integer elements from `N` to `M` than these values can be stored as one line `N-M` in the file . Using such approach a file can be written with less number of write operations. As a result it will be written faster.

Comment: @IIiar, the list wil never be sorted. That was interesting what you mentioned there by writing it all to one line. It could be integers between 0- any integer number actually. In reality it shouldn't be more than 5000000 elements in the list. I am thinking now how one could write all those to one line as you said?

Comment: @Andreas For example, there is an array `{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10}`. If we write an algorithm that can detect ranges in this array, than we can store this array in the file using three lines and three write operations (instead of 8): `1-4`, `6-8`, `10`. Main point is that we can optimize algorithms using properties of the input data (for example, input data is a list of integers where: 1. list has length of 5_000_000, 2. each integer is between 0-9_999_999). For the case when elements can be any int values such approach cannot be used (because max value of `int` is much more than 5_000_000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BufferedStream` won't help because `FileStream` already has a buffer.

Using `BinaryWriter` can help because you will write 4 bytes (one integer) instead of 6* bytes (three chars of 2 bytes, and we should count the newlines too) 5 000 000 times. However the file written will be binary. It won't be human-readable anymore.

In your example, because you always write the same number `123`, I think using compression will do some magic too ;)

Comment: I tried to use `BinaryWriter` but my file was full of `{`. I am not sure if I did that correct: `writer.Write(list1[i]);`? (Integers will differ and be different from: 0- 9999999) perheps.

Comment: @Andreas yes, it's writes the binary data representing the integer 123 whereas your code does write the characters "123", that's why I said the file won't be human-readable anymore. You'll have to use BinaryReader in C# to read again the integers that you wrote. That's the only solution I see to reduce the time of writing. You can also use compression to reduce even more the size of the file.

Comment: You are right. Your approach only takes 0.4 seconds as opposed to 1.77 seconds. It is actually 4 times faster. I will post the code as an answer.

Comment: @Andreas marking my answer as accepted should do the trick. I think using BinaryWriter rather than StreamWriter don't change so much your code

Comment: I just now marked your answer :) my head was still spinning from how to do it faster :). Yes It is not much change in the code. It is beautiful to use the BinaryWriter :)

Comment: at the end it's really about the number of bytes you are writing on the disk which matters, that's why compression would help too. If it takes 0.4 sec to write, say 25MB of data in a file, it means the speed is 62.5MB/s; and "a typical 7200 RPM HDD will deliver a read/write speed of 80-160MB/s"

Answer (score 0):

This approach takes 0.4 seconds using the BinaryWriter VS StreamWriter(1.77 seconds).
I wonder if it is possible to improve the speed even more?

```js
        void writeToFile()
        {
            List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
            {
                list1.Add(i);
            }

            //Approach takes: 0.4 seconds
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            BinaryWriter writer = null; FileStream fs = null;
            fs = new FileStream("C:/test.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite, 65536); writer = new BinaryWriter(fs);
            for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
            {
                writer.Write(list1[i]);
            }
            writer.Close(); fs.Close();

            DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan span = end - start;
            MessageBox.Show(span.TotalSeconds.ToString()); //Takes 0.4 seconds


            //Read the integers method
            using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open("C:/test.txt", FileMode.Open)))
            {
                // 2.
                // Position and length variables.
                int pos = 0;
                // 2A.
                // Use BaseStream.
                int length = (int)b.BaseStream.Length;
                while (pos < length)
                {
                    // 3.
                    // Read integer.
                    int v = b.ReadInt32();
                    // 4.
                    // Advance our position variable.
                    pos += sizeof(int);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`  is more appropriate for time measurements.